# php copy element text versus value

Tags: php

I have a php script below that basically updates option select values to the database. The script works if I want to copy the value of the option select. However, it doesn't work if I want to copy the text instead. What do I need to change to make the script copy the text instead of the value of the option select? For example, if an user selected "Second", I want the script to simply copy "Second" instead of "2". Thanks in advance.

```
<div class="controls">
  <i class="fa fa-sort"></i>
  <select class="floatLabel" name="prop_class" required>
    <option value="">None</option>
    <option value="Inline">First</option>
    <option value="2">Second</option>
    <option value="Last">Third</option>
  </select>
  <label for="prop_class">Property Class</label>
</div>
```

**php** script:

```
$cn = "235Miami";
$prop_class = $_POST['prop_class'];
$stmt1 = $DB_CON_C->prepare('UPDATE account
             SET prop_class=:prop_class
             WHERE cn=:cn');
$stmt1->bindParam(':cn', $cn, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt1->bindParam(':prop_class', $prop_class, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt1->execute();
```

Comment: `<option value="Second">` ?

Comment: When you submit a form, only the values are submitted, not the text.

Comment: Use mapping for template and other stuff. In that case you'll be able to convert values into labels and contra-versus.

Comment: `$POST_` should be `$_POST`.

Comment: The text isn't submitted. You'd use the `name` attribute which in turn would be `$_POST['your_name_attr_value'];` to get the element's `value` attribute.

Comment: Are there any ways for the script to take in the text instead of the value? Is it possible?

Comment: `<label for="prop_class">` needs to be matched with `id="prop_class"`. it doesn't match with `name="prop_class"`.

Comment: The value of what? You don't have any inputs with `name="one"`, `name="two"`, or `name="three"`?

Comment: @javystar, it's not possible, only values will be submitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create options map like this:

```
<?php
$options = [
   'Inline' => 'First',
   '2' => 'Second',
   'Last' => 'Third'
];
```

And then select proper value when inserting:

```
$key = $_POST['prop_class'];
$option = isset($options[$key]) ? $options[$key] : 'default value';
```

Comment: Thanks! This method works. I knew there's must a way to do this simple task, otherwise php limitation is questionable. Thanks Anton.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript for taking the text of the selected option in the select field when the form is submitted. Or you just can pass the value to the option in the select

```
<option value="Second">Second</option>
```